# convert maven plugin into gradle plugin

Tags: maven, gradle, maven-plugin, gradle-plugin

I'm planning to use aspects-jcabi for benchmarking my methods (http://aspects.jcabi.com/annotation-loggable.html).  However, it uses maven-plugin, and my project is on gradle.  I'm not yet that familiar with Gradle though.

Can I write the following in gradle (http://aspects.jcabi.com/example-weaving.html)?

```
<project>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.jcabi</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcabi-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.8</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>ajc</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```